# Xamarin.Android - Java Binding depends on Google Play Services

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, java-binding

We use several different types of Ad networks that we have to write our own Java bindings for. Since Google has made a new "advertising" id, all these libraries now have a dependency on Google Play Services.

The problem is, I can't get these binding projects to build properly after getting their latest versions. I get an error about missing classes, unless adding `google-play-services.jar` (from my `extras` folder in my Android SDK) as a `Reference Jar` to the project.

Once the play services jar file is added, I get a new error:

```
missing class error was raised while reflecting com.somepackage.SomeClass : com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesRepairableException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 JARTOXML
```

This error generally means the library is using Java 7 (not supported by Xamarin) from what I've read. What can I do to fix these binding projects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that Xamarin uses JDK 1.6 when your library was compiled with JDK 1.7.

In order to work around this, first install JDK 1.7 32-bit. Then in the *Progrm Files (x86)\Java* folder, rename the jdk1.6 folder to _jdk1.6.

When Xamarin runs it will now find the JDK 1.7 folder and use that. So far I haven't had any issues building apps with Xamarin and JDK 1.7.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd switch back to Java 1.6 in Xamarin Studio / Visual Studio after you finish with your binding.You could run into some oddities in the future as Xamarin doesn't officially support java 1.7.

Comment: Actually, that's no longer true. Xamarin supports JDK 1.7 see http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Installing_Java_SDK_(JDK)  In fact, it is required to support API level 21+.

Comment: Freakin' thanks mate :D You saved me a huge headache !